# How to get the list of all files in all branches?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Is there any way to get the list of all files (say all js or all css files) in my repo across ALL THE BRANCHES.

For example:

In my 'default' branch, i might not have a file named file1.js.
But in another branch named 'NEW_BRANCH', file1.js may exists.

I wanted to get the list of all files from one place or one command.

Comment: What if file `oops` was committed, and then removed again? It's still in a commit, but it's not in any head. Do you want to list it?

Comment: No. How to exclude that?

Comment: You will need to apply `hg manifest` or `hg files` against each head in each branch, then. [aflp91's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52454874/1256452) will get you close, but if there are multiple heads within some branch(es), you'll need to decide what to do about that too.

Comment: (See planetmaker's updated answer, now.)

Answer (score 3):

What about getting all files from all revisions including those still present, renamed and deleted?

```
hg manifest --all
```

If you only want files from the top of all branches (thus heads, then we iterate over all named and unnamed branches), you'll have to resort to some bash or similar, e.g.

```
for h in $(hg heads -T"{rev}\n"); do hg ma -r$h; done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: That's the fast way, *if* the OP's answer to my comment-question is "yes, list it".

Comment: Indeed... I'll make an amendment.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing as?:

> for b in `hg branches|cut -d ' ' -f 1` ; do echo "${b}: " ; hg manifest -r "branch(${b})"|grep ".css" ; echo